# How to compare files having variable date in name

Tags: bash, awk

This is `file2-$(date +%H).txt`:

```
line1
line2
```

This is `file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt`:

```
line2
```

These are my failed attempts which had no results:

```
awk -v now="$(date +%H)" -v an_hour_ago="$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H')" 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' 'file1-'now'.txt' 'file2-'an_hour_ago'.txt'
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' "file1-$(date +%H).txt" "file2-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt"
```

The expected output:

```
line1
```

The reason I use `date` is that I should name my files with the `date` command to compare the current hour file with the last hour file.

How can I compare thse files as expected?

When I run my first command, I get `No such file or directory` for `file1-now.txt` and `file2-an_hour_ago.txt`, but in the second I see nothing in the output.

Comment: The output  of `date` can change between two invocations. If it's 7:59, the file you create with `%H` will have an `07` in its name, but one second later, `date +%H` will start reporting `08`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements stipulates existence of files named

```
file2-$(date +%H).txt
file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt
```

whilst your 2nd command does look for

```
file1-$(date +%H).txt
file2-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt
```

which might result in

> I see nothing in the output.

if these files incidentally exist, after repairing that following test

```
echo -e "line1\nline2" > file2-$(date +%H).txt
echo -e "line2" > file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' "file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt" "file2-$(date +%H).txt"
```

gives desired result namely

```
line1
```

whilst using GNU Awk 5.1.0.

Comment: Oops, yes. I may have some mistakes in the sample. But that's strange, because I'm again checking my actual command with files, and I'm getting the result. I tested what you wrote before asking but not sure why it didn't work. I just moved the double quotations to both ends of file name. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sample command `comm` which will do this on the fly:

```
comm -3 "file1-$(date +%H).txt" "file2-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt"
```

Option `-3` will tell `comm` to display only lines available in `file1` and not available in `file2`

P.S. Seems OP mess with `file` and `file2` so maybe the command (for OP) must be:

```
comm -3 "file2-$(date +%H).txt" "file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt"
```

Comment: your command show me this error : `comm: file1-05.txt: No such file or directory`!

Comment: @Freeman, so you do not have such file. Maybe in question OP make mistake with `file1` and `file2`

Answer (score 1):

I think that for simpler problems like this, it might be better to use `grep` or `diff` instead of `awk`.

so first of all I will create two text files,each containing the specified lines.

```
printf "line1\nline2\n" > file2-$(date +%H).txt

printf "line2\n" > file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt
```

Now to compare the files and get the desired result I will use `grep` like below:

```
grep -Fxv -f file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt file2-$(date +%H).txt
```

- `-F`: treat the patterns as fixed strings
- `-x`: matching whole lines only.
- `-v`: inverting the match, so it displays lines that do not match.
- `-f`: reading the patterns from the specified file (`file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt`)!

or you can use `diff` :

```
diff file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt file2-$(date +%H).txt
```

but the output is like this :

```
0a1
> line1
```

so to fix this you can use `--unchanged-line-format=` option

```
diff --unchanged-line-format= file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt file2-$(date +%H).txt
```

now output is

```
line1
```

or with `comm`

```
comm -23 <(sort file2-$(date +%H).txt) <(sort file1-$(date -d '1 hour ago' '+%H').txt)
```

output

```
line1
```

good luck!